# Can I chose where an app is installed using apt?

Tags: apt

I just switch from Windows to Ubuntu. I have 2 drives, one is a HDD and another is an SSD. I use my SSD for the home directory, documents, and apps I use all the time. I use the hard drive for programs and games.

I have steam and I can chose where steam installs games. But when I download non games or games without steam I don't get an option to chose where to download them. I used to be able when I ran the MSI or EXE to chose where to download the app. In linux it's different where you use apt. How do I chose where to download stuff?

Comment: How do you "download stuff"? Which app does not ask you to "where to download" that file? Firefox or Chrome...?

Comment: See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go. Departing from the Standard places one at risk of becoming broken and unsupportable.

Comment: The directories where the packages get installed (*location being directories*) is set by the packager of whatever you install. You control where that goes by your install/setup, and what drive/partitions you use.